# Connecting to DB2 database using C++

Tags: c++, database, visual-c++, db2

How do we connect to DB2 database using C++.

Note: I am using visual C++ 2008 as the IDE for writing the code.

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: Research on the web "DB2 OLE C++"